# ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have some problems with this code.
I'm trying to create a dynamically list of news with this format:

---

```
|image| - title
|image|- subtitle
```

---

this is my little cicle code (a example with random data)

```
void setListNews(List<Map<String,String>>l){
        listaNewsPagina = l;
        final Iterator ite = listaNewsPagina.iterator();
        LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_sezione_news);
        LinearLayout lineare = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lineare);
        while(ite.hasNext()){
            Map<String,String> map = (Map<String, String>) ite.next();
            ImageView imm = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.immagine);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);
            TextView titolo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titolo);
            TextView sottoTitolo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sottoTitolo);
            titolo.setText("titolooooo");
            sottoTitolo.setText("sottoTitoloooooooooooo");
            rl.addView(titolo);
            rl.addView(sottoTitolo);
            lineare.addView(imm);
            lineare.addView(rl);
        }
        lin.addView(lineare);
            setContentView(lin);
```

and this is my layout:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear_sezione_news"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_homepage" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lineare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#aadd99"
         >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/immagine"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="#abfc99">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titolo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sottoTitolo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titolo"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewNews"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ImageButtonPrecc"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lineare"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#aadd99"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center" >

    </ListView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButtonPrecc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bottone_prev"
        android:text="@string/load_news" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButtonSucc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bottone_next"
        android:text="@string/load_news" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

when I launch the activity with this code I have this problem:

> 05-19 09:12:45.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21729): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

I'm trying to create a layout with only Java code...but nothing XD
where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_sezione_news);
```

to

```
RelativeLayout lin = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_sezione_news);
```

The id `linear_sezione_news` is assigned to a `RelativeLayout` so you can't cast it to `LinearLayout`

Comment: ...this stupid problem! XD
the next time i read better my code ;)
very thanks

Comment: now this error: java.lang.NullPointerException

at the line: titolo.setText("titolooooo");